# JavaScript video in browser: how to load mp4 video by modifying this sample code?

Tags: javascript, video

I found sample code for loading the user's webcam (which works), but I'd like to modify it to run 'myvideo.mp4' in the project folder. Here is the existing code:

```
async function setupVideo2() {
  if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    throw new Error(
        'Browser API navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not available');
  }

  const video2 = document.getElementById('video2');
  video2.width = videoWidth2;
  video2.height = videoHeight2;

  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    'audio': false,
    'video': {
      facingMode: 'user',
      width: videoWidth2,
      height: videoHeight2,
    },
  });
  video2.srcObject = stream;

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    video2.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      resolve(video2);
    };
  });
}
```

I have this code already called elsewhere and it works and returns the user's webcam. So I figure modifying this I should be able to use arbitrary video sources, e.g. an MP4 file I have in my project folder.

Comment: `getUserMedia` is for accessing a media input device, ie camera or microphone.

Comment: OK, so how do I put an MP4 video into srcObject ?

Comment: You can use the built in video tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: can I just do `video2.srcObject = './video_example.mp4';` ? edit - I get `TypeError: Failed to set the 'srcObject' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided value is not of type 'MediaStream'.`

Answer (score 1):

> *"...Can I just do `video2.srcObject = './video_example.mp4';`?
>   I get TypeError: Failed to set the `'srcObject'` property on `'HTMLMediaElement'`: The provided value is not of type `'MediaStream'`."*

No you must use `.src` to set a file path, not using `srcObjecct`.

```
function setupVideo2() 
{
    const video2 = document.getElementById('video2');
    video2.width = videoWidth2;
    video2.height = videoHeight2;
    
    video2.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"; //# testable video link
}
```